# Pandas vectorized way to get counts using conditional statement between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes (with unequal rows, but the same columns) such as the following.

DataFrame A:

```
dummy | probability
-------------------
  0   |    .1
-------------------
  0   |    .2
```

DataFrame B:

```
dummy | probability
-------------------  
  1   |    .05
-------------------
  1   |    .2
```

What I would like to do is implement a vectorized conditional check for pairwise elements.

My actual dataset has a few hundred thousand elements. So if I check element wise, using a double for loop would require at least 100000^2 iterations which I do not want at all.

I believe there is probably a way to do this using numpy and pandas that I am currently unaware of.

pseudocode should look something like this:

```
def vectorized_counts():

    A = 0
    B = 0
    tie = 0

    if element in dfA second column > element in dfB second column:
        A += 1
    elif element in dfA second column < element in dfB second column:
        B += 1
    else:
        tie += 1

    return list(A,B,tie)
```

For my test example above, we have:

```
A
.1 > .05
.2 > .05

B
.1 < .2

tie
.2 = .2
```

Hence:

```
A = 2
B = 1
tie = 1
```

What way can I go about this? It is simple enough to compare one element of a dataframe with the corresponding element of another dataframe. What is confusing me is how to compare every element of a dataframe with every element of another dataframe.

Comment: You're going to have to pick between millions of iterations, or a massive memory requirement.  Outer comparison is easy, but if each column has 300_000 elements, you're going to need an intermediate array that is holding 90000000000 elements

Comment: In a situation where I have, let's say, 10,000 elements in each column, what would you suggest to do? I may have to reduce my data set regardless as it maybe does not offset the memory issue. Can you please expand on outer comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an iteration-less function that (hopefully) does what you need:

```
def compare_probabilities(A, B):
    df = pd.concat([A] * B.shape[0], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
    df['Ap'] = df.probability
    df['Bp'] = B.probability.repeat(A.shape[0]).values
    AgtB = (df.Ap > df.Bp).sum()
    BgtA = (df.Ap < df.Bp).sum()
    #AeqB = (df.Ap == df.Bp).sum()
    AeqB = df.shape[0] - (AgtB + BgtA)
    return AgtB, BgtA, AeqB

A = pd.DataFrame({'dummy':[0,0], 'probability':[0.1,0.2]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'dummy':[1,1], 'probability':[0.05,0.2]})
print ("compare_probabilities: A>B is %d; B>A is %d;  A==B is %d"%compare_probabilities(A, B))
```

This should display:

`compare_probabilities: A>B is 2; B>A is 1;  A==B is 1`

And it should work for unequal row sizes in A and B.

Comment: You only need to create two of the masks, the third is just arithmetic from the first two.  It avoids creating another large mask.

Comment: This works like a charm. Using the repeat command was a great idea. Agreed though that only using two masks is the way to go as the third is just total - A - B.

Comment: changed solution to be more efficient as per suggestion